# How to know whether a chain is a boundary?

Tags: real-analysis

Well,

Suppose $c$ is a $k$-chain in some open set $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, Spivak says in his Calculus on Manifolds that $\partial c =0$ doesn't imply that $c$ is the boundary of some $k+1$ chain.

With differential forms, we know that if $\omega$ is some $k$ form in the open set $U$, then $d\omega = 0$ doesn't imply that there is some $k-1$ form $\eta$ with $\omega=d\eta$. However, if we add the hypothesis that $U$ is contractible then $\eta$ exists.

Is there some hypothesis that when added to $U$ grants that $\partial c = 0$ imply $c$ being the boundary of some other chain $r$?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Do you mean $\partial c=0$ rather than $\partial^2c=0$?

Comment: That's right, it was a typo. I'm going to edit. Thanks @Brad.

Comment: Well, if the $k$-th (reduced) homology group is trivial, then every $k$-cycle is a boundary. If $U$ is contractible, for example, all reduced homology groups are trivial.

Comment: The assertion you made about differential forms isn't exactly correct -- I think you mean that $U$ should be contractible rather than simply connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hypothesis is that the $k$th *homology group* of $U$ is zero. I'm not sure what coefficients you are using for your chains, so I will assume you allow only integer coefficients here (but the story works for coefficients in other abelian groups).

Let $Z_k$ denotes the set of closed $k$-chains in $U$, i.e. those $k$-chains $c$ such that $\partial c=0$, and let $B_k$ denote the set of boundary $k$-chains, i.e. those $k$-chains $c$ such that $c = \partial a$ for some $(k+1)$-chain $a$. Each of $B_k$ and $Z_k$ is an abelian subgroup of the group of all $k$-chains.

Since $\partial^2=0$, we have $B_k\subset Z_k$. The $k$th **homology group** of $U$ is defined to be the quotient group

$$H_k(U,\mathbb{Z}) = Z_k/B_k.$$

It can be shown that this is a homotopy invariant, i.e. if $U$ and $V$ are homotopic then they have isomorphic homology groups. In particular, this is true if $U$ and $V$ are homeomorphic.

By definition, we have $H_k(U,\mathbb{Z})=0$ if and only if $Z_k=B_k$, which is exactly the condition that every $k$-chain $c$ with $\partial c=0$ is the boundary of some $(k+1)$-chain.

One topological condition to guarantee that this happens is if $U$ is contractible (homotopic to a single point). In this case, $U$ has the same homology groups as a point, which are all zero (except for $k=0$).

Regarding the result you state about differential forms, there is a map from the $k$th homotopy group to the $k$th homology group,

$$\pi_k(U)\to H_k(U,\mathbb{Z}),$$ called the Hurewicz map. Part of the [Hurewicz theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurewicz_theorem) says that this map is surjective for $k=1$. So if $U$ is simply connected, which is equivalent to saying that its first homotopy group $\pi_1(U)$ is trivial, then the Hurewicz theorem implies that $H_1(U,\mathbb{Z})$ is also trivial.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP is referencing De Rham cohomology (notice how $k$-"chains" are "forms" and called $\omega$, how $\partial$ raises the degree...), not (I guess singular) homology.